# Eevee is broken (Don't know how to describe it)

Tags: eevee-render-engine

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dg28IKO2dkw&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=KPidS

[image]

Does anyone know what the heck is that? Eevee is just broken and I have no idea how to google that

Comment: What graphics card are you using? To add a bit of context, another user commented on a different question saying that there are problems with the latest AMD driver, so perhaps try installing a previous version of the driver, if infact you have an AMD GPU of course.

Comment: I'll second this - Latest AMD Adrenalin drivers are the cause. Many, many complaints recently.

Comment: Yes, I have an AMD GPU, RX580. Which version should I install exactly?